# pandas: handling a DataFrame with a large number of strings

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read and handle a large CSV file (`data_file`) having the following 2-columns structure:

```
id params
1  '14':'blah blah','25':'more cool stuff'
2  '157':'yes, more stuff','15':'and even more'
3  '14':'blah blah','25':'more cool stuff'
4  '15':'different here'
5  '157':'yes, more stuff','15':'and even more'
6  '100':'exhausted'
```

This file contains 30.000.000 lines (5 Gb on disk). (The actual strings are encoded in UTF-8; for simplicity, I gave them in ascii here). Note that some of the values in the 2nd column are repeated.

I read this using `pandas.read_csv()`:

```
df =  pandas.read_csv(open(data_file, 'rb'), delimiter='\t', 
         usecols=['id', 'params'],dtype={'id':'u4', 'params':'str'})
```

Once the file is read, the data frame `df` uses 1.2 Gb of RAM.

So far so good.

Now comes the processing part. I want to have the `params` string column with this format:

```
blah blah||more cool stuff
yes, more stuff||and even more
blah blah||more cool stuff
different here
yes, more stuff||and even more
exhausted
```

I wrote:

```
def clean_keywords(x): 
    return "||".join(x.split("'")[1:][::2])

df['params'] = df['params'].map(clean_keywords)
```

This code works in the sense it gives the correct result. But:

1. More than 6.8 Gb of RAM are used while performing the `map` operation.
2. After computation has been finished, 5.5 Gb of RAM are used by  `df` (after `gc.collect()`), although the string computed in `params` column is shorter than the one that was read.

Can someone explain this and propose an alternative way of performing the above operation using pandas (I use python 3.4, pandas 0.16.2, win64) ?

Comment: Your code produces this: `Out[69]:
   id                                   params
0   1       14||blah blah||25||more cool stuff
1   2  157||yes, more stuff||15||and even more` which is equivalent to `df['params'].str.split("'").str[1:].str[::2].str.join('||')`

Comment: @EdChum, I have simplified the original code I actually wrote . Maybe I made a mistake ? I don't get what you want to tell me. Your code is more efficient ? I just tried your code: RAM goes above 7 Gb.

Comment: It maybe as this is vectorised `str` method it may be worth trying to modify your code to use code similar to what I suggested, this may not solve your memory issue though

Comment: @EdChum I confirm: it doesn't help with RAM

Comment: Is it faster though?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82973/discussion-between-m-page-and-edchum).

Comment: is pandas a requirement, it would seem to me that it'd be easier just iterating through the file line by line doing a split on tab

Comment: No, I have simplified a lot. It would be nice to use pandas (I need to merge that dataframe with an other one, and so on).

Comment: @JohnE I see your comment a bit late. Yes, you are right ! That's the idea of my own answer, but there is probably a more elegant solution with categorical. Can you sketch it as an answer ?

Comment: @JohnE I tried your previous solution but I get: ValueError: incompatible categories in categorical concat when doing adsInfoDF = adsInfoDF.append(chunk)

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question.

It turns out that `pandas.read_csv()` is clever. When the file is read, strings are made unique. But when these string are processed and stored in the column, they are no longer unique. Hence the RAM usage increases. In order to avoid this, one has to maintain the uniqueness manually. I did it this way:

```
unique_strings = {}

def clean_keywords(x):
    s = "||".join(x.split("'")[1:][::2])
    return unique_strings.setdefault(s, s)

df['params'] = df['params'].map(clean_keywords)
```

With this solution, RAM max. usage was only 2.8 Gb and went down slightly under the initial RAM usage after reading data (1.2 Gb), as expected.

Comment: That's seems a useful technique to know.